# Should I adapt loss weights for misclassified samples during epochs?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using FCN (Fully Convolutional Networks) and trying to do image segmentation. When training, there are some areas which are mislabeled, however further training doesn't help much to make them go away. I believe this is because network learns about some features which might not be completely correct ones, but because there are enough correctly classified examples, it is stuck in local minimum and can't get out.

One solution I can think of is to train for an epoch, then validate the network on training images, and then adjust weights for mismatched parts to penalize mismatch more there in next epoch.

Intuitively, this makes sense to me - but I haven't found any writing on this. Is this a known technique? If yes, how is it called? If no, what am I missing (what are the downsides)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if I understand well you want your network to overfit your training set ? Because that's generally something you don't want to see happening, because this would mean that while training your network have found some "rules" that enables it to have great results on your training set, but it also means that it hasn't been able to generalize so when you'll give it new samples it will probably perform poorly. Moreover, you never talk about any testing set .. have you divided your dataset in training/testing set ?

Secondly, to give you something to look into, the idea of penalizing more where you don't perform well made me think of something that is called "AdaBoost" (It might be unrelated). This short video might help you understand what it is :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjtSo-YWCjc

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, actually AdaBoost is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't understand much of the video you linked, but this one explained it prefectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GM3CDQfQ4sw (Udacity). Otherwise you raise valid questions, but I think I am dogin this part right - I train and test on separate data. My issue is that even on training data model doesn't learn good enough, so I thought I would put more "weight" on those samples that were misclassified - which is sort of what AdaBoost does. So thank you, this is exactly what I needed to go forward!

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on your network structure. If you are using the original FCN, due to the pooling operations, the segmentation performance on the boundary of your objects is degraded. There have been quite some variants over the original FCN for image segmentation, although they didn't go the route you're proposing.

Just name a couple of examples here. One approach is to use Conditional Random Field (CRF) on top of the FCN output to refine the segmentation. You may search for the relevant papers to get more idea on that. In some sense, it is close to your idea but the difference is that CRF is separated from the network as a post-processing approach.

Another very interesting work is U-net. It employs some idea from the residual network (RES-net), which enables high resolution features from lower levels can be integrated into high levels to achieve more accurate segmentation.

This is still a very active research area. So you may bring the next break-through with your own idea. Who knows! Have fun!

Comment: I am actually using U-Net already (well, a bit modified). But thank you for mentioning CRF! It is not actually what I had in mind for training U-Net, but it sounds useful for next steps (classifying objects found on image and counting the number of instances for each class). Thank you very much, I think you just showed me the way past this! :)